# Regular expression group with name not considered numbered group

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone explain the behavior where a Regular Expression's named group sometimes is numbered like an unnamed group and sometimes it is not numbered.

For example:

```
var text = "The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

var pat1 = @"(?<sentence>(\w+(\s+|\.))+)";
var re1 = new Regex(pat1);
var m1 = re1.Match(text);
Console.WriteLine($"m1.Groups[\"sentence\"].Value: {m1.Groups["sentence"].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"         m1.Groups[0].Value: {m1.Groups[0].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"         m1.Groups[1].Value: {m1.Groups[1].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"         m1.Groups[2].Value: {m1.Groups[2].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"         m1.Groups[3].Value: {m1.Groups[3].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"         m1.Groups[4].Value: {m1.Groups[4].Value}");
Console.WriteLine();

// pat2 is the same as pat1 but without the name for the first group
var pat2 = @"((\w+(\s+|\.))+)";
var re2 = new Regex(pat2);
var m2 = re2.Match(text);
Console.WriteLine($"m2.Groups[0].Value: {m2.Groups[0].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"m2.Groups[1].Value: {m2.Groups[1].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"m2.Groups[2].Value: {m2.Groups[2].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"m2.Groups[3].Value: {m2.Groups[3].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"m2.Groups[4].Value: {m2.Groups[4].Value}");
Console.WriteLine();

var pat3 = @"The\s+(?<word>\w+)\s+brown.*$";
var re3 = new Regex(pat3);
var m3 = re3.Match(text);
Console.WriteLine($"m3.Groups[\"word\"].Value: {m3.Groups["word"].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"     m3.Groups[0].Value: {m3.Groups[0].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"     m3.Groups[1].Value: {m3.Groups[1].Value}");
Console.WriteLine($"     m3.Groups[2].Value: {m3.Groups[2].Value}");
Console.WriteLine();
```

Bearing the following result:

```
m1.Groups["sentence"].Value: The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         m1.Groups[0].Value: The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         m1.Groups[1].Value: dog.
         m1.Groups[2].Value: .
         m1.Groups[3].Value: The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
         m1.Groups[4].Value: 

m2.Groups[0].Value: The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
m2.Groups[1].Value: The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
m2.Groups[2].Value: dog.
m2.Groups[3].Value: .
m2.Groups[4].Value: 

m3.Groups["word"].Value: big
     m3.Groups[0].Value: The big brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
     m3.Groups[1].Value: big
     m3.Groups[2].Value:
```

I expected the result for **m1.Groups[1].Value** == **m2.Groups[1].Value** so with **m1.Groups[2].Value** and **m1.Groups[3].Value** I expected them to match that of **m2.Groups[2].Value** and **m2.Groups[3].Value** respectively.

The Regular expressions evaluator behaves like if the group is named (as it is in **pat1**, it is named "sentence") then it is not participating in the count as in **m1.Groups[1].Value**, and then the RE evaluator produces an unexpected **m1.Groups[3].Value** which is identical to **m1.Groups[0].Value** or what I would have exptected **m1.Groups[1].Value** to be.

Now, if a named groups are not participating in the group count then the third pattern pat3 (that has a named group: "word") behaves as I would expect.  Named group or not, first set of parentheses house group 1, second set of parentheses  house group 2, etc.

I could not find any literature that explains this behavior.  Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked [Named Matched Subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

@WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your reference.

The answer is: **unnamed** groups are captured first then **named** groups follow.

Therefore, **m1.Groups[1].Value** captures the first **unnamed** parentheses group, `(\w+(\s+|\.))`, **m1.Groups[2].Value** captures the second **unnamed** parentheses group, `(\s+|\.)` and lastly **m1.Group[3].Value** captures the first **named** parentheses group, `(?<sentence>(\w+(\s+|\.))+)`.